# Can you have multiple foreign keys in django? but using OR operater vs AND

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have contestants in different tables and I am creating a score table, What I want to do is set a foreign key between the score table and contestants tables however for each score there has to be one person from one of the two tables but not both. Is this something that is possible?

Models:

```
 class Couples_Round_1(models.Model):


     event = models.ForeignKey(comp_name, blank=True)

     dancer_1_fname = models.CharField('Dancer 1 First Name', max_length = 30)
     dancer_1_lname = models.CharField('Dancer 1 Last Name', max_length = 30)


class Couples_Round_2(models.Model):


     event = models.ForeignKey(comp_name, blank=True)

     dancer_1_fname = models.CharField('Dancer 1 First Name', max_length = 30)
     dancer_1_lname = models.CharField('Dancer 1 Last Name', max_length = 30)

class score (models.Model
     contestant = models.Foreignkey(round1, round2?????)
     judge = models.Foreignkey(judges)
     score1 = models.integerfield()
```

Comment: Could you please show your current models? Thanks.

Comment: Alright so I've added my models

Comment: Generic Foreign Key solves this problem: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have multiple foreign keys. However, one way to achieve this is, you can have 2 separate foreign keys, and handle the data validation at the application level.

Example:

```
class score (models.Model
     contestant_r1 = models.Foreignkey(round1, null=True)
     contestant_r2 = models.Foreignkey(round2, null=True)
     judge = models.Foreignkey(judges)
     score1 = models.integerfield()
```

Now, you can also handle the logic - example both `r1` and `r2` are required, either is required, etc..

I would re-consider the models

```
class Couples_Round(models.Model):
     round = models.IntegerField()    
     event = models.ForeignKey(comp_name, blank=True)

     dancer_1_fname = models.CharField('Dancer 1 First Name', max_length = 30)
     dancer_1_lname = models.CharField('Dancer 1 Last Name', max_length = 30)
     score = models.Foreignkey('score')
```

and point to these via the reverse relationship:

```
class score(models.Model):
    judge = models.Foreignkey(judges)
    score1 = models.integerfield()
```